# Need to get the .push values of predefined inputs pushed out on the page

Tags: javascript, html

I was not really sure how to explain my issue, so hopefully the code will explain.
The "user input" sections seems to be working fine, showing the message correctly a long with if they're of legal age or not.

But I want the predetermined users, "person1 and "person2" to be showing as well. I'm having issues mixing up the arrays.

(Comments of the code are variants I've tried but have not been working)

js

```
let nameElement = document.getElementById("UNameInput");
let faultElement = document.getElementById("errorOutput");
let ageElement = document.getElementById("AgeInput");
let clickElement = document.getElementById("button");
let passwordElement = document.getElementById("PasswordInput");
let corrElement = document.getElementById("output");


clickElement.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    let feedback = [];
    let ages = [];
    let names = [];

    names.push("Person1");
    names.push("Person2");

    ages.push(33);
    ages.push(35);


    /*
    people.push(new person1("Marcus", 33));
    people.push(new person2("Cihan", 35));
    */

    if (UNameInput.value === '' || UNameInput.value === null) {
       alert('Name input missing')
    }

    else if (AgeInput.value === '' || AgeInput.value === null) {
        alert('Age input missing')
    }
    else if (PasswordInput.value !== 'IHM') {
        alert('Password is not valid')

    } else if (AgeInput.value !== ''){
        if (ageElement.value < 18) {
                feedback.push ( 
                    `Hi your name is ${UNameInput.value}. You are ${AgeInput.value} years old, which is not of legal age. Have a nice day!`
                );
                e.preventDefault()
            
            }
        else {
                feedback.push(
                    `Hi your name is ${UNameInput.value}. You are ${AgeInput.value} years old, which makes you of legal age in Sweden. Have a nice day!`
                );
                e.preventDefault()
            }
    }

    if (feedback.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        corrElement.innerText = feedback.join(", ")
    }
    else if (names.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        corrElement.innerText = names.join(", ")
    }

    else if (ages.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        corrElement.innerText = ages.join(", ")
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="errorOutput"></div>  
    <p id="output"></p>
        <div>
            <label for="UNameInput">Name Input</label>
            <input id="UNameInput" name="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="AgeInput">Age Input</label>
            <input id="AgeInput" name="age" type="number">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="PasswordInput">Password Input</label>
            <input id="PasswordInput" name="password" type="password">
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want the users to show up?

Comment: It doesnt really matter, in the <p id="output"> would work!

Comment: And what's the structure you want them to be. I am trying to understand the use case to help you. Also why don't you use objects to store your info like `people.push({ name: "Marcus", age: 33 });`

Comment: What do you mean by structure? Sorry, I am new to coding. I'm trying to figure out what the best way to solve this issue is. Have you got any recommendations on what would be the best option?

Comment: First of all you don't need to push the element into the arrays you have, so you can remove `names.push (nameElement);`. Same goes for the ageElement. Other than that the last part you have commented seems fine and it will show the names or the ages if the conditions are met.

Comment: I have now deleted those parts of the code. I removed the following comment, and made it active in the code. `else if (names.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        corrElement.innerText = names.join(", ")
    }

    else if (ages.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        corrElement.innerText = ages.join(", ")
    }`    Is this correct? EDIT: I tried running the code, and the only this output into the HTML in browser was what was input by me as a user.

Comment: Update the code in your post so that I can havea look at it

Comment: I have now edited the code the way I interpreted your previous comment.

Comment: your code misses the button on which you are adding the onclick event. If you create the button and click it without filling anything into your inputs you'll see that the names appear in your output element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240007/discussion-between-cossab-and-babis-amas).